# Minimalistic Java Code Formatter / Formatting Tool To ONLY fix certain aspects (eg whitespace in expressions)

Tags: java, software-development, code-beautification, formatter

Java code formatters that I'm aware of (eclipse JDT, intellij, astyle, prettier) are all quite aggressive and try to change all the code format aspects that they are technically capable of. However, I would prefer the opposite approach: a code formatter that leaves the code completely unchanged by default, and only interferes in formatting aspects that are explicitly configured. For example: only remove whitespace characters between method names and parenthesis and add whitespace between operators and operands in expressions, while leaving everything else as-is. Is anyone aware of such a tool?

I know some formatters have the option to not interfere in certain aspects (like the "never join already wrapped lines" in eclipse JDT), but still many other unwanted changes are done to the code. I'm also aware of the option to add pragmas/special comments to suppress formatting in certain code sections, however this also just adds manual effort which I would like to avoid at all costs.

I'm looking for a cross-platform tool (linux + windows) that could be executed from the command line. On top, ideally there would be eclipse/intelliJ plugins or maven plugins. It doesn't have to be a free or even open source tool, as long as the licensing is hassle-free.

Comment: Just FYI, on many IDEs if you select a block of text with the mouse and then auto format, only the range of lines you selected will be formatted.  Not exactly what you are asking for, but I often use this feature to prevent overly aggressive formatters from changing too much in my code.

Comment: `I'm looking for a cross-platform tool (linux + windows) that could be executed from the command line.` Oh ouch, never mass format an entire file, it messes up the change history in source code control systems.

Comment: _Oh ouch, never mass format an entire file, it messes up the change history in source code control systems_

That's actually precisely my goal: clean up the whole code base and fix a few syntactic problems where there are no two options how a human would do it. I don't mind a huge "reformat" commit. Requiring a targeted re-format for the few remaining open development branches is a minor problem that we can deal with.